# what is the basic logic behind random number generation?

Tags: .net, random

```
private void RandomNumber_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random randnumber = new Random();
            MessageBox.Show(randnumber.Next(1, 150).ToString());
        }
```

in vb 6.0 random numbers are generated but if we quit the application and restart it again then the order of random number generation is same where as in dotnet it is not like that random number generation is perfect! how is it possible ? what is the logic behind it ?

Comment: As an unrelated comment, don’t instantiate a new `Random` every time you need one. Declare a static one for your whole application. This is not only more efficient, but also more random: People have run into problems when instantiating a new `Random` inside a tight loop.

Comment: @Timwi: Good advice about not firing up a new `Random` every time you need one, but... Sharing a static `Random` throughout the whole app has its own pitfalls. The `Random` class isn't thread-safe so if you are sharing it throughout your app then you need to ensure that access is synchronised somehow (eg, with a lock) or use `ThreadStatic`/`ThreadLocal<T>` rather than a plain static.

Comment: Good advice Timwi.  The seed for Random in .Net is TickCount which is why it is different (for testing you can seed it with a known value and get identical results).  Knuth's TAOCP Chapter 3 goes into much detail about random number generators.  .Nets random is based on his work I believe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Random generator is basically a deterministic function making one number from another. If you start from a given value, you'll always end in the same result. Usually (to randomize) first input to random generator is generated from current time (this is known as seed). .NET just do that as default, vb 6.0 probably not.

Quote from J. von Neumann

> Any one who considers arithmetical methods of producing random digits is, of course, in a state of sin.

Answer (score 2):

Providing truly random numbers has always been one of the hardest challenge in computer science. The problem is not solved. I can guarantee you that in .NET, random number generation is by no means "perfect". It's just a notch better than in VB6.

[Redgate Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/download.aspx?TreatAsUpdate=1) revelas that in .NET, the default constructor of the Class Random() provides Environment.TickCount as the default seed (milliseconds since last boot). VB6 probably has a constant as the default value.

Comment: I can't agree with the first statement. Providing random numbers of arbitrary strength based on various entropy sources is a deeply studied and thoroughly solved problem, and has been so for decades. Producing an implementation of such that isn't vulnerable to determined attackers is a technical challenge, but that's an engineering problem, not a computer science problem. Pseudo-random number generators like the one proffered up by the Random class are of course not random at all; they don't even attempt to solve the problem of truly random number generation.

Answer (score 2):

In VB6, one usually calls

```
Randomize Timer
```

in order to get a different sequence of numbers each time.

Answer (score 0):

In dotNet `Random` class uses the current system time as seed. It seems like vb 6.0 always uses the same seed.

Answer (score 0):

I was told a couple of days ago that when instantiating a new Random class its the same as

```
Random r = new Random(Environment.TickCount);
```

This is why the number is different

Comment: That's basically what you'll see if you open up Reflector and see the default constructor for Random.  public Random() : this(Environment.TickCount) {}